# Node + vue js user offline/online status(server side)

Tags: node.js, vue.js

I want to be able to see if the user is currently browsing on the site or not. I know that you can detect if the user is offline/online client side but I want to monitor whether they are on and show a status message/colour.

How would I do this that isn't PHP and not socket io since I believe some firewalls block socket io from connecting which would break my application.

I use vue js and node js and want to detect if a user is currently browsing and use it server side. Other solution I found was set timeout but how to target this at a user and not a server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, since you dont want to use sockets, then your user table should have a `is_active` column. and in the front end, in the entry point of your application you call your api to set the active status to 1 which means that they are online.

your back-end controller could be something like this, using express

```
const app = express();

app.post('/users/active-status/:id', (req, res, next) => {
   const userId= req.params.id;
   const status = req.params.activeStatus

  // then find the user and set the is_active status to status variable

  next();
});
```

and in your front end you can listen to close events, function and set the user active status to 0

your root component

```
// when the user enters the website he is active
axios.post('/users/active-status/'+ userId, {
    activeStatus: 1
});


// check before they leave and set the active status to 0
window.onclose= function (e) {
    axios.post('/users/active-status/'+ userId, {
       activeStatus: 0
    });
};



window.addEventListener('offline', function(event){
    // the user has lost connection here
});
```

Comment: Thanks, how would I implement a check if they suddenly lose connection or something?

Comment: you can listen for network events inside the vue js by using js online and offline events

Comment: i have included that in my answer now, please vote this if this solves your issue, and happy coding